# How to Convert DateTime to boolean in ASP.NET GridView?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, gridview

I have a column with DateTime datatype. i want to display value of this column as Yes/No in GridView in ASP.NET. if DateTime field "Is Null" then Display "No" and If Datetime field column "Is Not Null" then display "No" in grid view how to do it.Whether to do it in SQL Query or in GridView binding.

I have tried in GridView but it fails.I know the following  code is wrong & in SQLQuery i have checked it for ISNULL.

```
<ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblOndate" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("OnDate")) ? "Yes" : "No" %>' ReadOnly="true">
       </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Help Appreciated!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "I have tried": *what* did your try and *how* did it fail? Is that value in a DataSet or something else? Is it a plain DateTime (can't be null) or a nullable DateTime? Please edit and extend your question.

Comment: Your always showing "No" per your definition.

Comment: how to display it using SQL Select query. if DateTime column is Null then display "No" if Not Null then display "Yes"...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the GridView without any checking in SQL.  Just amend your code in the GridView to check for `DBNull.Value` instead of attempting to convert to a boolean.

i.e.

`<asp:Label ID="lblOndate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OnDate") == DBNull.Value ? "No" : "Yes" %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        DateTime? dt = row.Field<DateTime?>("OnDate");
        Label lblOndate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblOndate");
        lblOndate.Text = dt.HasValue ? "Yes" : "No"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a Function in code behinde and call in by parameter in geidview column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_SPORT_TYPE" runat="server" Text='<%#StatusName(Eval("SPORT_DATE")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind:

```
Public Function StatusName(ByVal SportDate As DateTime?=nothing) As String
    If SportDate Is Nothing Then
        Return "yes"
    Else
        Return "no"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property for the DateTime field column in the gridview NullDisplayText="NO